# Transferring money

Tags: banking, bank-account

A friend working in South Africa had his American bank account closed due to a hacking incident. He now wants to get his payout check transferred into my Australian account as he is coming to Australia.

Is this Ok to do?

Comment: Why are you asking our permission?

Comment: How well do you know him? What is he asking you to do? What information is he asking for? We need a lot more details -- this could be scam. Perhaps he'll ask you to wire him the money because he's not coming to Australia anymore and then you'll find out the check was fake.

Answer (score 2):

How good a friend?  Is this someone you would loan that amount of money without security?  Is this someone you trust not to be involved in some illegal transaction that might get you in trouble?  If you can answer yes to both of the latter two questions, then I would say that this is a good enough friend.

There are a couple things that can go wrong.

1. Your friend may be receiving money illegally.  By using your account, it is possible that you could be the one prosecuted for breaking the law.  And once you give your friend the money, you won't even be benefiting from breaking the law.  That would be a bad deal.  It can be even worse if the problem is that your friend is being honest but naive and helping a fraudster.  Then it's not your friend's honesty that is in question but his good sense.

   If the person is a good enough friend that you are confident that this is not an issue and you are confident that there isn't a third party involved who could be scamming both of you, then this may be safe.
2. Your "friend" may actually be a scammer.  He arranges for money to be deposited into your account such that it will be withdrawn later. But in the meantime, you withdraw money from your account and turn it over as cash.  He disappears and your account is empty or even overdrawn.

   Again, this is really dependent on how well you know and trust this person.

In general, it is safer not to get involved with things like this.  It puts you in the middle if anything goes wrong with the payment.  It would be much better for your friend to establish his own account and deposit the money there.

There is an active scam that works like this.  They put money in your account.  You hand over cash.  They abscond with the cash and the money put in your account is withdrawn.

Also, if they are transferring the money to your account, you might have to give out account details for them to do that.  Under no circumstances should you give your account information to a third party.  That screams scam to me.

Comment: The warning about giving out account information is a bit broad. There's a minimum amount of account information needed for any transfer. Every check has your account number and bank routing number, they are necessary. You shouldn't have to give out your username/password for a transfer, just be mindful about what info you are being asked to divulge, and make sure you're not giving someone more what is minimally necessary.